# Creating Dr and Cr Lines - Balancing Lines || Splitting Rows || SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I will try to explain the problem with an example. I have a table: xxtb_je_txn

```
CREATE TABLE XXTB_JE_TXN 
( "ENTITY" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"JE_HEADER_ID" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
"NET_CR" NUMBER, 
"NET_DR" NUMBER
);

Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('401','10101',0,30);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('302','10101',0,20);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('402','10101',0,50);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('301','10101',100,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('402','10102',50,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('301','10102',0,100);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('401','10102',30,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('302','10102',20,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('102','10103',0,400.44);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10103',992.57,325.17);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('201','10103',0,266.96);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('102','10105',62.5,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('201','10105',0,17291);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10105',17228.5,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('204','10104',200,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10104',0,200);
```

It will look like this:

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 10101 | 0 | 30 |
| 302 | 10101 | 0 | 20 |
| 402 | 10101 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10101 | 100 | 0 |
| 402 | 10102 | 50 | 0 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 100 |
| 401 | 10102 | 30 | 0 |
| 302 | 10102 | 20 | 0 |
| 102 | 10103 | 0 | 400.44 |
| 101 | 10103 | 992.57 | 325.17 |
| 201 | 10103 | 0 | 266.96 |
| 102 | 10105 | 62.5 | 0 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 17291 |
| 101 | 10105 | 17228.5 | 0 |
| 204 | 10104 | 200 | 0 |
| 101 | 10104 | 0 | 200 |

I want to split the  row to create the Balance entries like:

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 10101 | 0 | 30 |
| 302 | 10101 | 0 | 20 |
| 402 | 10101 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10101 | 30 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 20 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 50 | 0 |
| 402 | 10102 | 50 | 0 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 30 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 20 |
| 401 | 10102 | 30 | 0 |
| 302 | 10102 | 20 | 0 |
| 102 | 10103 | 0 | 400.44 |
| 101 | 10103 | 400.44 | 0 |
| 101 | 10103 | 266.96 | 0 |
| 201 | 10103 | 0 | 266.96 |
| 102 | 10105 | 62.5 | 0 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 17228.5 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 62.5 |
| 101 | 10105 | 17228.5 | 0 |
| 204 | 10104 | 200 | 0 |
| 101 | 10104 | 0 | 200 |

How to Achieve This?

Tried so far.

```
select  s1.entity,
        s1.je_header_id,
        nvl(l.net_cr,s1.net_cr) net_cr,
        nvl(l.net_dr,s1.net_dr) net_dr
  from  XXTB_JE_TXN s1,
        lateral(
                select  s2.net_dr net_cr,
                        s2.net_cr net_dr
                  from  XXTB_JE_TXN s2
                  where s2.je_header_id = s1.je_header_id
                    and s1.net_cr != 0
                    and s2.net_cr = 0
               )(+) l
  order by je_header_id,
           net_cr;
```

Output is wrong for JE_HEADER_IDs: 10102 and 10105

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 10101 | 0 | 30 |
| 302 | 10101 | 0 | 20 |
| 402 | 10101 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10101 | 30 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 20 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 50 | 0 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 100 |
| 302 | 10102 | 100 | 0 |
| 402 | 10102 | 100 | 0 |
| 401 | 10102 | 100 | 0 |
| 102 | 10103 | 0 | 400.44 |
| 101 | 10103 | 400.44 | 0 |
| 101 | 10103 | 266.96 | 0 |
| 201 | 10103 | 0 | 266.96 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 17291 |
| 102 | 10105 | 17291 | 0 |
| 101 | 10105 | 17291 | 0 |

tried this and this also produced the wrong results:

```
SELECT
    c.entity,
    c.je_header_id,
    CASE
        WHEN c.net_cr = 0 THEN
            0
        ELSE
            d.net_dr
    END AS net_cr,
    CASE
        WHEN c.net_cr = 0 THEN
            c.net_dr
        ELSE
            0
    END AS net_dr
FROM
         xxtb_je_txn c
    JOIN xxtb_je_txn d ON d.je_header_id = c.je_header_id
                          AND sign(d.net_cr) <> sign(c.net_cr)
ORDER BY
    je_header_id,
    net_cr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a correct balance, for each JE_HEADER_ID total cr == total dr. Also for each JE_HEADER_ID only one total cr/dr row exists. Replace the total row with its non-total components.

```
with t as (
select ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID, greatest(0, NET_CR-NET_DR)NET_CR, greatest(0, NET_DR-NET_CR) NET_DR
  , sum(greatest(0, NET_CR-NET_DR)) over(partition by JE_HEADER_ID) tot
from XXTB_JE_TXN 
)
select a.*
from t
cross join lateral (
  select t.ENTITY,t.JE_HEADER_ID,t2.NET_CR,t2.NET_DR
  from t t2
  where t2.JE_HEADER_ID = t.JE_HEADER_ID and t2.tot != t2.NET_CR and t2.tot != t2.NET_DR
) a
where t.tot = t.NET_CR or t.tot = t.NET_DR
  
union all
  
select ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_DR,NET_CR
from t
where t.tot != t.NET_CR and t.tot != t.NET_DR
order by 2, 1;
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mGK8Pw__)

Comment: Thanks @Serg. This is helpful. But let's say we have two more rows in Source Table XXTB_JE_TXN with JE_HEADER_ID as 10104. I've updated the source table

This query removes 10104 rows from the result set.

Comment: @rish, yes, the query ignores 10104 rows because they don't match the assumptions I've maid looking at the provided sample data. You may want to rephrase this question, or perhaps ask another one specifing all the essential requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have posted an expanded version of this question, including all the necessary assumptions, in this new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502072/splitting-rows-to-balance-lines-oracle-sql). Could you please provide your help once again

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
WITH sumed AS (
  SELECT entity, je_header_id, 
  net_cr, SUM(net_cr) OVER(PARTITION BY je_header_id) AS sum_net_cr, 
  net_dr, SUM(net_dr) over(partition by je_header_id) AS sum_net_dr
  FROM xxtb_je_txn
),
tsumed as (
    SELECT entity, je_header_id, net_cr, sum_net_cr, net_dr, sum_net_dr,
    CASE 
        WHEN net_cr = sum_net_dr THEN 2
        WHEN net_dr = sum_net_cr THEN 3
        WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM xxtb_je_txn x WHERE x.net_cr = s.sum_net_dr
            ) AND net_dr <> 0 AND net_dr <> sum_net_cr
        THEN 1
        WHEN EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1 FROM xxtb_je_txn x WHERE x.net_dr = s.sum_net_cr
                )
                AND net_cr <> 0 AND net_cr <> sum_net_dr
            THEN 2
        END AS flag
    FROM sumed s
)
SELECT entity, je_header_id, r_net_cr as net_cr, r_net_dr as net_dr --, flag
FROM tsumed s
MODEL
    PARTITION BY ( je_header_id )
    DIMENSION BY ( entity )
    MEASURES( 0 AS r_net_cr, 0 AS r_net_dr, net_dr as net_dr, net_cr as net_cr, flag as flag )
    RULES(
        r_net_cr[any] =
            CASE 
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 1 THEN net_dr[cv()]
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 2 THEN 0
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 3 THEN net_dr[cv()]
        END,
        r_net_dr[any] =
            CASE 
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 1 THEN net_cr[cv()]
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 2 THEN net_cr[cv()]
            WHEN flag[cv()] = 3 THEN 0
        END
    )
ORDER BY je_header_id, entity
;

301 10101   0   100
302 10101   20  0
401 10101   30  0
402 10101   50  0
301 10102   100 0
302 10102   0   20
401 10102   0   30
402 10102   0   50
101 10103   0   992,57
102 10103   400,44  0
201 10103   266,96  0
101 10104   200 0
204 10104   0   200
101 10105   0   17228,5
102 10105   0   62,5
201 10105   17291   0
```

Comment: Thank you, @p3consulting, for your response. However, the result of this query does not align with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, missing the "swapped" CR/DR rows:

```
WITH sumed AS (
  SELECT entity, je_header_id, 
  net_cr, SUM(net_cr) OVER(PARTITION BY je_header_id) AS sum_net_cr, 
  net_dr, SUM(net_dr) over(partition by je_header_id) AS sum_net_dr
  FROM xxtb_je_txn
),
tsumed as (
    SELECT entity, je_header_id, net_cr, sum_net_cr, net_dr, sum_net_dr,
    CASE 
        WHEN net_cr = sum_net_dr THEN CASE WHEN net_dr <> 0 THEN 5 ELSE 2 END
        WHEN net_dr = sum_net_cr THEN CASE WHEN net_cr <> 0 THEN 6 ELSE 4 END
        WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM xxtb_je_txn x WHERE x.net_cr = s.sum_net_dr
            ) AND net_dr <> 0 AND net_dr <> sum_net_cr
        THEN 1
        WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM xxtb_je_txn x WHERE x.net_dr = s.sum_net_cr
            )
            AND net_cr <> 0 AND net_cr <> sum_net_dr
        THEN 3
        END AS flag
    FROM sumed s
)
SELECT entity, je_header_id, net_cr, net_dr FROM (
    SELECT flag, entity, je_header_id, net_cr, net_dr
    FROM tsumed s
    MODEL
        PARTITION BY ( je_header_id )
        DIMENSION BY ( entity, flag )
        MEASURES( net_dr as net_dr, net_cr as net_cr, 
            sum_net_cr as sum_net_cr, sum_net_dr as sum_net_dr )
        RULES UPSERT ALL(
            net_cr[any,5] = net_cr[cv(),1],
            net_dr[any,5] = net_dr[cv(),1],
            net_cr[any,6] = net_dr[cv(),1],
            net_dr[any,6] = net_cr[cv(),1],
    
            net_cr[any,7] = net_cr[cv(),3],     
            net_dr[any,7] = net_dr[cv(),3],
            net_cr[any,8] = net_dr[cv(),3],     
            net_dr[any,8] = net_cr[cv(),3],
    
            net_cr[any,9] = net_cr[cv(),0],     
            net_dr[any,9] = net_dr[cv(),0],
    
            net_cr[any,10] = case when net_cr[cv(),2] = sum_net_cr[cv(),2] and net_dr[cv(),2] <> 0 then net_dr[cv(),2] end,     
            net_dr[any,10] = case when net_cr[cv(),2] = sum_net_cr[cv(),2] and net_dr[cv(),2] <> 0 then 0 end,
    
            net_cr[any,11] = case when net_dr[cv(),4] = sum_net_dr[cv(),4] and net_cr[cv(),4] <> 0 then net_cr[cv(),4] end,     
            net_dr[any,11] = case when net_dr[cv(),4] = sum_net_dr[cv(),4] and net_cr[cv(),4] <> 0 then 0 end,
            
            net_cr[any,12] = net_dr[cv(),5],        
            net_dr[any,12] = 0,
            
            net_cr[any,13] = 0,     
            net_dr[any,13] = net_dr[cv(),5],
            
            net_cr[any,14] = net_cr[cv(),6],        
            net_dr[any,14] = 0,
            
            net_cr[any,15] = 0,     
            net_dr[any,15] = net_cr[cv(),6]
        )
)
WHERE net_cr is not null AND net_dr is not null AND flag > 4 
ORDER BY je_header_id, entity
;
```

Comment: Thank you, @p3consulting. I am sorry but this solution also does not produce the desired output.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT entity, je_header_id, net_cr, net_dr FROM...

Comment: Yes, did that. Still, it doesn't.