# Splitting Rows To Balance Lines || Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table: xxtb_je_txn

```
CREATE TABLE XXTB_JE_TXN 
( "ENTITY" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
"JE_HEADER_ID" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
"NET_CR" NUMBER, 
"NET_DR" NUMBER
);

Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('401','10101',0,30);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('302','10101',0,20);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('402','10101',0,50);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('301','10101',100,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('402','10102',50,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('301','10102',0,100);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('401','10102',30,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('302','10102',20,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('102','10103',0,400.44);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10103',992.57,325.17);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('201','10103',0,266.96);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('102','10105',62.5,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('201','10105',0,17291);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10105',17228.5,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('204','10104',200,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('101','10104',0,200);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('301','10106',70,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('302','10106',30,0);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('401','10106',0,60);
Insert into XXTB_JE_TXN (ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_CR,NET_DR) values ('402','10106',0,40);
```

It will look like this:

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 10101 | 0 | 30 |
| 302 | 10101 | 0 | 20 |
| 402 | 10101 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10101 | 100 | 0 |
| 402 | 10102 | 50 | 0 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 100 |
| 401 | 10102 | 30 | 0 |
| 302 | 10102 | 20 | 0 |
| 102 | 10103 | 0 | 400.44 |
| 101 | 10103 | 992.57 | 325.17 |
| 201 | 10103 | 0 | 266.96 |
| 102 | 10105 | 62.5 | 0 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 17291 |
| 101 | 10105 | 17228.5 | 0 |
| 204 | 10104 | 200 | 0 |
| 101 | 10104 | 0 | 200 |
| 301 | 10106 | 70 | 0 |
| 302 | 10106 | 30 | 0 |
| 401 | 10106 | 0 | 60 |
| 402 | 10106 | 0 | 40 |

I want to split the  row to create the Balance entries like:

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 10101 | 0 | 30 |
| 302 | 10101 | 0 | 20 |
| 402 | 10101 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10101 | 30 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 20 | 0 |
| 301 | 10101 | 50 | 0 |
| 402 | 10102 | 50 | 0 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 50 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 30 |
| 301 | 10102 | 0 | 20 |
| 401 | 10102 | 30 | 0 |
| 302 | 10102 | 20 | 0 |
| 102 | 10103 | 0 | 400.44 |
| 101 | 10103 | 400.44 | 0 |
| 101 | 10103 | 266.96 | 0 |
| 201 | 10103 | 0 | 266.96 |
| 102 | 10105 | 62.5 | 0 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 17228.5 |
| 201 | 10105 | 0 | 62.5 |
| 101 | 10105 | 17228.5 | 0 |
| 204 | 10104 | 200 | 0 |
| 101 | 10104 | 0 | 200 |

For rows with JE_HEADER_ID = 10106, there is no clear-cut association of net_cr and net_dr between Entities. So query should ignore these rows and flag them like this.

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR | ERROR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 10106 | 70 | 0 | REJECT |
| 302 | 10106 | 30 | 0 | REJECT |
| 401 | 10106 | 0 | 60 | REJECT |
| 402 | 10106 | 0 | 40 | REJECT |

How to Achieve This?

The query provided by [@Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219979/serg) was helpful, but it does not include rows with JE_HEADER_ID 10104, as I did not mention those rows in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495031/creating-dr-and-cr-lines-balancing-lines-splitting-rows-sql/76495327?noredirect=1#comment134885445_76495327). The solution worked well for the original question. Therefore, I am rephrasing the question with all the necessary assumptions (Two New Sets of Rows with JE_HEADER_IDs 10104 and 10106).

```
with t as (
select ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID, greatest(0, NET_CR-NET_DR)NET_CR, greatest(0, NET_DR-NET_CR) NET_DR
  , sum(greatest(0, NET_CR-NET_DR)) over(partition by JE_HEADER_ID) tot
from XXTB_JE_TXN 
)
select a.*
from t
cross join lateral (
  select t.ENTITY,t.JE_HEADER_ID,t2.NET_CR,t2.NET_DR
  from t t2
  where t2.JE_HEADER_ID = t.JE_HEADER_ID and t2.tot != t2.NET_CR and t2.tot != t2.NET_DR
) a
where t.tot = t.NET_CR or t.tot = t.NET_DR
  
union all
  
select ENTITY,JE_HEADER_ID,NET_DR,NET_CR
from t
where t.tot != t.NET_CR and t.tot != t.NET_DR
order by 2, 1;
```

Comment: 10104 is [doable](https://dbfiddle.uk/zR_gGsLv), but 10106 looks like a variation of [Exact hitting set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT entity,
       je_header_id,
       SUM(net_cr) AS net_cr,
       SUM(net_dr) AS net_dr,
       MAX(note) AS note
FROM   (
  SELECT entity,
         je_header_id,
         CASE WHEN type = 'CR' THEN amount END AS net_cr,
         CASE WHEN type = 'DR' THEN amount END AS net_dr,
         CASE WHEN min_group_size = 1 THEN 'ACCEPT' ELSE 'REJECT' END AS note
  FROM   (
    SELECT je_header_id,
           COALESCE(
             e_cr,
             LEAD(e_cr) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
               PARTITION BY je_header_id
               ORDER BY total, amount
             )
           ) AS e_cr,
           COALESCE(
             e_dr,
             LEAD(e_dr) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
               PARTITION BY je_header_id
               ORDER BY total, amount
             )
           ) AS e_dr,
           LEAST(
             COUNT(net_cr) OVER (PARTITION BY je_header_id),
             COUNT(net_dr) OVER (PARTITION BY je_header_id)
           ) AS min_group_size,
           total - LAG(total, 1, 0) OVER (
               PARTITION BY je_header_id
               ORDER BY total, amount
           ) AS amount
    FROM   (
      SELECT je_header_id,
             ABS(net_cr - net_dr) AS amount,
             CASE
             WHEN net_cr > net_dr
             THEN net_cr - net_dr
             END AS net_cr,
             CASE
             WHEN net_dr > net_cr
             THEN net_dr - net_cr
             END AS net_dr,
             CASE WHEN net_cr > net_dr THEN entity END AS e_cr,
             CASE WHEN net_dr > net_cr THEN entity END AS e_dr,
             SUM(ABS(net_cr - net_dr)) OVER (
               PARTITION BY je_header_id, SIGN(net_cr - net_dr)
               ORDER BY ABS(net_cr - net_dr)
             ) AS total
      FROM   xxtb_je_txn
    )
  )
  UNPIVOT (
    entity FOR type IN (
      e_cr AS 'CR',
      e_dr AS 'DR'
    )
  )
  WHERE  amount > 0
)
GROUP BY
       je_header_id,
       entity,
       CASE note WHEN 'REJECT' THEN NULL ELSE ROWNUM END
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

| ENTITY | JE_HEADER_ID | NET_CR | NET_DR | NOTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 10101 | 20 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 302 | 10101 | *null* | 20 | ACCEPT |
| 301 | 10101 | 30 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 401 | 10101 | *null* | 30 | ACCEPT |
| 301 | 10101 | 50 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 402 | 10101 | *null* | 50 | ACCEPT |
| 302 | 10102 | 20 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 301 | 10102 | *null* | 20 | ACCEPT |
| 401 | 10102 | 30 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 301 | 10102 | *null* | 30 | ACCEPT |
| 402 | 10102 | 50 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 301 | 10102 | *null* | 50 | ACCEPT |
| 101 | 10103 | 266.96 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 201 | 10103 | *null* | 266.96 | ACCEPT |
| 101 | 10103 | 400.44 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 102 | 10103 | *null* | 400.44 | ACCEPT |
| 204 | 10104 | 200 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 101 | 10104 | *null* | 200 | ACCEPT |
| 102 | 10105 | 62.5 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 201 | 10105 | *null* | 62.5 | ACCEPT |
| 101 | 10105 | 17228.5 | *null* | ACCEPT |
| 201 | 10105 | *null* | 17228.5 | ACCEPT |
| 302 | 10106 | 30 | *null* | REJECT |
| 402 | 10106 | *null* | 40 | REJECT |
| 301 | 10106 | 70 | *null* | REJECT |
| 401 | 10106 | *null* | 60 | REJECT |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m17HVhb-)

Comment: Thanks, @MTO for the response. It is helpful.
The only thing is that for JE_HEADER_ID = 10103, rows with 325.17 should not appear in the output. The row **101 10103 992.57 325.17** in the source should evaluate to **101 10103 667.4 0** and then should be split into two rows

101 10103 266.96 null ACCEPT and 
101 10103 400.44 null ACCEPT

Can you please help to update the query?

Comment: @rish Updated. Just subtract the lower of `net_cr` and `net_dr` from each of those values at the start.

Answer (score 1):

My try. Tested for your input and it shows correct result. It is similar to queries matching transactions, except additional logic for *rejected* rows:

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zE3GZRCq)

```
with t as (
  select ENTITY ent, JE_HEADER_ID id,          
         greatest(NET_CR-NET_DR, 0) cr, greatest(NET_DR-NET_CR, 0) dr,
         sum(greatest(NET_CR-NET_DR, 0)) 
           over (partition by JE_HEADER_ID order by NET_CR, rowid) scr, 
         sum(greatest(NET_DR-NET_CR, 0)) 
           over (partition by JE_HEADER_ID order by NET_DR, rowid) sdr
  from XXTB_JE_TXN),
c as (select ent, id, cr, scr-cr c1, scr c2 from t where cr > 0),
d as (select ent, id, dr, sdr-dr d1, sdr d2 from t where dr > 0),
m as (
  select cent, dent, id, cr, dr, val, cc, cd,
         max(case when cc > 1 and cd > 1 then 'rejected' end) 
             over (partition by id) status
  from (
    select c.ent cent, d.ent dent, c.id, cr, dr, --c1, c2, d1, d2,
           least(cr, c2-d1, dr, d2-c1) val,
           count(1) over (partition by c.id, c.ent) cc, 
           count(1) over (partition by c.id, d.ent) cd
    from c join d on c.id = d.id and c1 < d2 and d1 < c2) )
select t.ent, t.id, case status when 'rejected' then t.cr else m.val end cr, 
       0 dr, m.status 
from t join m on t.id = m.id and t.ent = m.cent 
where t.cr >= 0 and (cc < 2 or cd < 2)
union all
select t.ent, t.id, 0 cr, 
       case status when 'rejected' then t.dr else m.val end dr, m.status 
from t join m on t.id = m.id and t.ent = m.dent 
where t.dr >= 0 and (cc < 2 or cd < 2)
order by id, cr, dr
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ponder Stibbons for the response. It is helpful. The only thing is that for JE_HEADER_ID = 10103, rows with 325.17 should not appear in the output. The row 101 10103 992.57 325.17 in the source should evaluate to 101 10103 667.4 0 and then should be split into two rows 101 10103 266.96 0  and 101 10103 400.44 0. Can you please help to update the query?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that both values can be non zero in one row. It requires minor change in first subquery. Corrected, [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vqijrv1B).

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use [MODEL Clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) which is very usefull, reliable and fast. It works prety much like working with excel sheet. So, it could be a good choice when you need to work with different sets of rows or columns or with individual cells within the dataset.
With data provided, I created a cte (grid) to prepare the dataset...

*(Code adjusted after the comment below)*

```sql
 WITH grid AS
    (   Select    JE_HEADER_ID, ENTITY, NET_CR, NET_DR,
                  GREATEST(Sum(NET_CR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID),
                  Sum(NET_DR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID)) "TOTAL",
                  Case When Count(*) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) = 2 Then 'TXN'
                       When NET_CR = Sum(NET_CR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) And NET_DR != 0 Then 'TOT/TXN'
                       When NET_CR = Sum(NET_CR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) And NET_DR = 0  Then 'TOT'
                       When NET_DR = Sum(NET_DR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) And NET_CR != 0 Then 'TOT/TXN'
                       When NET_DR = Sum(NET_DR) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) And NET_CR = 0  Then 'TOT' 
                  Else 'TXN'
                  End "AMOUNT_TYPE",
                  Row_Number() Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID Order By JE_HEADER_ID, ENTITY) "RN",
                  Count(*) Over(Partition  By JE_HEADER_ID) "MAX_RN"
        From      XXTB_JE_TXN
        Order By  JE_HEADER_ID, ENTITY 
    )
```

...and then used the [MODEL Clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) to get the result...

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L
SELECT  ENTITY, JE_HEADER_ID, NET_CR, NET_DR, ACCEPTED
FROM    (  Select  JE_HEADER_ID, IDX, RN, MAX_RN, AMOUNT_TYPE, ENTITY, Nvl(NET_CR, 0) "NET_CR", Nvl(NET_DR, 0) "NET_DR", Nvl(TOTAL, 0) "TOTAL", ACCEPTED
            From (  Select    0 "IDX", JE_HEADER_ID, RN, MAX_RN, ENTITY, NET_CR, NET_DR, TOTAL, AMOUNT_TYPE, 'YES' "ACCEPTED"
                    From      grid  
                 )
            MODEL     Partition By   (JE_HEADER_ID)
                      Dimension By  (IDX, RN, AMOUNT_TYPE)
                      Measures       (ENTITY, NET_CR, NET_DR, TOTAL, ACCEPTED, MAX_RN)
            RULES   ITERATE(6)
              (   NET_DR[1, ITERATION_NUMBER + 1, 'TXN'] =  CASE WHEN NET_CR[0, CV(RN), 'TXN'] != 0 THEN NET_CR[0, CV(RN), CV()] ELSE 0 END, 
                  --
                  NET_CR[1, ITERATION_NUMBER + 1, 'TXN'] =  CASE WHEN NET_DR[0, CV(RN), 'TXN'] != 0 THEN NET_DR[0, CV(RN), CV()] ELSE 0 END,
                  --
                  ACCEPTED[ANY, ANY, ANY] =  CASE   WHEN MAX_RN[CV(), CV(), CV()] = 2 And ( NET_CR[0, 1, 'TXN'] = NET_DR[0, 2, 'TXN'] OR NET_DR[0, 1, 'TXN'] = NET_CR[0, 2, 'TXN'] ) THEN 'YES'
                                                    WHEN Max(TOTAL)[IDX = 0, RN > 0, AMOUNT_TYPE Like '%TOT%'] > 0 Then 'YES' 
                                            ELSE 'NO' 
                                            END,
                  ENTITY[1, ANY, 'TXN'] =  ENTITY[0, CV(RN), 'TXN']
              )
        )
WHERE      Nvl(NET_CR, 0) + Nvl(NET_DR, 0) != 0  And AMOUNT_TYPE != 'TOT' And 
           TOTAL != CASE WHEN ACCEPTED = 'NO' THEN 0 ELSE TOTAL + 1 END And
           (  (NET_CR = 0 And TOTAL IN(0, TOTAL)) OR (NET_DR = 0 And TOTAL IN(0, TOTAL))  )
ORDER BY JE_HEADER_ID, RN, IDX
```

```sql
--      R e s u l t :
--  
--  ENTITY  JE_HEADER_ID  NET_CR  NET_DR  ACCEPTED
--  ------  ------------ ------- -------  --------
--  302     10101                0      20  YES
--  302     10101               20       0  YES
--  401     10101                0      30  YES
--  401     10101               30       0  YES
--  402     10101                0      50  YES
--  402     10101               50       0  YES
--  302     10102               20       0  YES
--  302     10102                0      20  YES
--  401     10102               30       0  YES
--  401     10102                0      30  YES
--  402     10102               50       0  YES
--  402     10102                0      50  YES
--  102     10103                0  400.44  YES
--  102     10103           400.44       0  YES
--  201     10103                0  266.96  YES
--  201     10103           266.96       0  YES
--  101     10104                0     200  YES
--  204     10104              200       0  YES
--  101     10105          17228.5       0  YES
--  101     10105                0 17228.5  YES
--  102     10105             62.5       0  YES
--  102     10105                0    62.5  YES
--  301     10106               70       0  NO
--  302     10106               30       0  NO
--  401     10106                0      60  NO
--  402     10106                0      40  NO
```

Comment: Thanks, @d r for the response. It is helpful. The only thing is that for JE_HEADER_ID = 10103, rows with 325.17 should not appear in the output. The row 101 10103 992.57 325.17 in the source should evaluate to 101 10103 667.4 0 and then should be split into two rows 101 10103 266.96 0 YES and 101 10103 400.44 0 YES.
Also, it is removing Rows with JE_HEADER_ID = 10104.

Comment: @rish Just comment out  modelings for 'TOT/TXN' (starting wih IDX 2,3,4,5 )  - that is even shorter code without covering combination of values in the same row. Check the Where clause too.

Comment: @rish Just posted the code that should result as expected after the comment.

Comment: Thank you, @d r, for your response. However, the result of this query now does not align with the expected output.